# Grammatical structure

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, relative-clauses, participles

> Mental energy is a vital element **needed to be able to concentrate one's attention and maintain a positive mental attitude.**

The question I want to ask is how the section in bold is functioning over here. It is acting like a complement or it is modifying some word? Please could you explain   the structure of the sentence?

Comment: It's a deleted version of 'Mental energy is an element which is needed for a person to be able to concentrate their attention on a matter and maintain a positive mental attitude'.

Comment: The past-participial clause in bold is functioning as **modifier** of the noun "element". Semantically, it is similar to the relative clause "which is needed to be able ...", but we don't call it a relative clause since its internal structure is different.

Comment: @Billj:  Careful with the use of _we_ here. ***You*** don't call it a reduced relative clause. ***I*** do, however. So do many other linguists. It's just another way to analyze clauses; there is no ISO for syntactic terminology.

Comment: The crucial point is that a relative clause has an element that is anaphorically related to an antecedent from which it derives its interpretation -- this is the basis for the term 'relative clause'. But gerund-participials and past-participials lack this crucial property. They may still modify nouns, but that's no reason to call them 'reduced' relative clauses. They are a different kind of clause, semantically similar, but syntactically quite different since there's no possibility of them containing a relative phrase. I think this is a better and more logical way to categorise such clauses.